# Determine if the set of functions is Linearly Independent or LD

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

My matrix and the following distribution of derivatives:

[image]

So to determine the Independence or dependency of the set we have to take 2nd order derivative of each function. Then we distribute the terms and set it equal to zero.

Am I on the right track with my process? I’m not sure because my class has been moved online and don’t have someone around who knows this level of math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great attempt!

Minor mistake is remember to flip your sign as you use Laplace expansion.

You obtained

\begin{align}&-x^2\color{red}{+}2x\sin x \cos x \color{red}{-}2\sin^2 x-2x\sin x \cos x -2 \cos ^2x \\
&=-x^2-2\\
&=-(x^2+2) \ne 0\end{align}

Hence the functions are linearly independent.

A relevant keyword might help in looking up for relevant readings: Try [Wronskian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian).

Comment: When using The Wornskian, do I keep taking their derivative’s until one of the three equal zero or does the given dictate how many derivatives to take?

Comment: And also when multiplying the four terms within a given matrix, the proper sequence of operations is: Top Left $*$ Bottom Right $-$ Top Right $*$ Bottom Left, correct?

Comment: if you have $n$ functions, take derivatives $n-1$ to form a square matrix to take determinant. Pick a row or column, expand along that row or column, remember to switch your sign between $1$ and $-1$.